# Runtime Error with copy.deepcopy in Python

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I need to manipulate a large list of objects. Now, I need to invoke `copy.deepcopy` and it raises a `RunTimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` (Its OK when I try it with a smaller list.). My question is: Is there any other way to get the feature of `copy.deepcopy` which does not have this problem? Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've probably an extremely deep structure.  You should increase your recursion limit:

```
 sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)  # default is 1000 in my installation
```